# json formatting when merging array within another

Tags: javascript, php, json

$result1 value

```
[{"uId":"1","firstName":"James","lastName":"Bond"}]
```

$result2 value

```
[{"task":"teaching"},{"task":"tutoring"}]
```

and I wish to put array $result2 within $result1 I do

```
$result1['task'] = $result2;
echo json_encode($result1);
```

I got:

```
{"0":{"uId":"1","firstName":"James","lastName":"Bond"},"task":[{"task":"teaching"},{"task":"tutoring"}]}
```

I expect it be like this?

```
[
    {
        "uId": "1",
        "firstName": "James",
        "lastName": "Bond",
        "task": [
            {
                "task": "teaching"
            },
            {
                "task": "tutoring"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have to add the `'task'` to the first element of `$result1`.

```
$result1[0]['task'] = $result2;
echo json_encode($result1);
```

If `$result1` and `$result2` are both stdClass but not array, try:

```
$result1 = (array)$result1;
$result2 = (array)$result2;

$result1[0]['task'] = $result2;
echo json_encode($result1);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @user3522457 So `$result1` is a stdClass not an array? the point is same.

Comment: I don't know what is a stdClass mean, but when I do json_encode($result1) before the merge, it returns [{"uId":"1","firstName":"James","lastName":"Bond"}]

Comment: @user3522457 Try `$result1->{0}->task`

Comment: you ask me to echo that?

Comment: @user3522457 `$result1` is a stdClass object, you could either convert it to array or use it like above.